Barplot group_by with two variables
I have a data set in which information about children's writing skills is stored at two measurement points in time. For example:
textscores <- data.frame (class = c("5050", "5050", "4040", "4040", "3030", "3030"), 
ExCon = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1"), textscores_t1 = c(3.5, 2, 4, 5.5, 2.2, 3.9), 
textscores_t2 = c(4, 5.8, 6, 3, 5.6, 4))

ExCon means wether the class is part of our experimental group (group 1) or control group (group 2).
I then converted the data set into a long format:
textscores_long <- textscores %>%
  rename ("August 2023" = textscores_t1,
          "Februar 2024" = textscores_t2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("August 2023", "Februar 2024"), names_to = "MZP", values_to = "Textscores")

I can create a bar plot that contains the columns of the overall mean value and a specific class at two measurement times:
textscores_long %>%
  bind_rows(textscores_long %>% mutate(class = 'all')) %>%
  group_by(class, MZP) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Textscores, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(class %in% c('5050', 'all')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = MZP, y = Mean, fill = class)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "orange"),
                    name = "Legend",
                    labels = c("Your class", "Overall Mean")) +
  labs (y = "Mean", 
        x = "Time") +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_cartesian(
    ylim = c(0, 8)) 

And I can create a bar chart in which the experimental and control groups are compared at the two measurement times:
textscores_long %>%
  group_by (ExCon, MZP) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Textscores, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = ExCon, y = Mean, x = MZP)) +
  geom_bar(position= 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
  xlab ("Time") +
  ylab ("Mean") +
  scale_fill_manual ("Group", values = c("steelblue", "orange"), labels = c("Experimental group", "Control group"))

I would now like to create a bar plot, which contains the two measurement times on the x-axis as well as the control and experimental group and the column of a specific class as columns. The y-axis should reflect the mean value of the text scores. So, I guess it is a mixture of both diagrams I have so far. But I do not know how to combine the information.
Any suggestions?

df1 <- textscores_long %>%
  bind_rows(textscores_long %>% mutate(class = 'all')) %>%
  group_by(class, MZP) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Textscores, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(class %in% c('5050', 'all')) %>% 
  mutate(grp = "class") %>% 
  rename("name" = class)


df2 <- textscores_long %>%
  group_by (ExCon, MZP) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Textscores, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(grp = "ExCon") %>% 
  rename("name" = ExCon)

rbind(df1, df2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = MZP, y = Mean, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "orange", "tomato", "mediumseagreen"),
                    name = "Class",
                    labels = c("Your class", "Overall Mean", "Experimental group", "Control group"))

